# Where is the fourth stone?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've found the P stone, L stone, A stone, but i dont know how to find the last stone. I have done almost everything except the third room in the desert temple.

Comment: Never mind, i have to kill the developer

Comment: If you discovered the answer on your own, feel free to post an answer with that information! (It's okay to do that on your own questions.)

Comment: Sorry i'm just a guest. I cant do that :/

Comment: You can answer your own question after 8 hours of posting it iirc

Answer (score 2):

You get the fourth stone when you kill the developer.